# How do I get the GUI to come back?

Tags: boot, startup, gui

My computer for some reason is no longer booting into the GUI. It sends me straight to the command line. How do I get it to launch the GUI and how do I get it to launch the GUI by default on startup? I'm using Lucid Lynx.

Comment: What happened before your GUI stopped coming up on boot?

Comment: @Roland Taylor, I'm not sure. My computer crashed, then when it came back up, it took me straight into the command prompt and has done that on every bootup since

Comment: Assuming it has a network connection, please run `sudo apt-get install pastebinit && pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and edit your question to include the URL that that gives you (it *is* case sensitive)

Comment: @KathrynHallett: What graphics chip/card do you have?
Btw, if you can log in to the system from the command line, try running `sudo start gdm`.

Comment: Doesn't look like I have a network connection, and the other two solutions by @Roland and wismonkey don't work. I would love to know why this stopped working, but since it's a brand new Ubuntu install, I think it would be easier to reinstall Ubuntu. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KathrynHallett: I guess if that is the case (a fresh install), reinstalling is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

This may not serve as an answer (but I can't comment yet):
 when u login on terminal type `startx` and see if that starts GUI for you or as Roland said try `sudo start gdm` 
 Once your GUI starts you can provide more details easily as Oli is expecting to fix starting directly in GUI.
 If none of those work then you may have to work on terminal and provide more details.

Best luck :)

Comment: Roland is my name :), not Ronal :D

Comment: oops sorry just fixed it :)

Comment: I had to use "sudo startx" since I wasn't logging in as root.  I am using an NVidia GeForce GTX 460.  Hopefully the proprietary drivers will help.  I'll try that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the login screen by running:
sudo start lightdm

This was in Ubuntu 12.04.1 though so YMMV.