# After Installing 12.04.1 I Have No GUI?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the GUI to come back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57201/how-do-i-get-the-gui-to-come-back)
>   [How to start GUI from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168736/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line)

I installed 12.04.1 and installation seemed to go fine.
But now i have no GUI.
My screen shows the following:

`bob@bob-desktop:"$`

Comment: Would the person who down-voted our answer & this question please explain why? Thanks

Comment: @FernhillLinuxProject Yes, downvoting with no comment is frustrating. It's usually because the question is an obvious dupe and shows no effort to search first, or is off-topic. This one is a dupe of [several](http://askubuntu.com/q/57201/12864) [others](http://askubuntu.com/q/168736/12864), so I'm down-voting the question, up-voting your answer, and also casting a close vote. Your answer is fine though, it matches the answers at the linked duplicates.

Comment: ..... what? This question is bizarre. Could you clarify, do you boot *directly* to this prompt, or do you get it after doing somethiing else? I can think of no way that you could be logged into your user account directly after booting... try restarting an please describe in more detail.

Comment: You probably didn't use the same installation media as the first time.  That is probably why someone who isn't me downvoted.  Look at either how do I install a gui for ubuntu server or how do I start a gui from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following command,

```
startx
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Would the person who down-voted our answer & this question please explain why? Thanks

Comment: Works with a slight modification: sudo startx.  Same thing is happening to me.  Using NVidia GeForce GTX 460.  I'm guessing installing the proprietary drivers will probably help.  I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Didn't work as expected.  I get the graphical environment, but there are no icons or controls so it's non-functional.