# I messed up bad on upgrading my OS, need help!

Tags: upgrade

I'm a Linux noobie who has been using Linux for almost a year now and I have encountered many problems I can't resolve on my own but none of that matters now as I have messed up so bad I think Linux isn't for me and I should stick with windows (I don't want to). So I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and only an hour ago I decided I want to upgrade to 15.10 as I thought it would resolve some issues I've been having. I upgraded via the terminal in 14.04 and now when I turn on my laptop and go to Ubuntu I get a big black screen with a terminal command and I can't do anything. There's no GUI or home screen. I'm scared please help me.

Comment: do you see any error messages? do you see a prompt asking for username/password in text mode or just a black empty screen ?

Comment: It prompts to answer my user name and password then goes right to a terminal command.

Comment: you can try starting the GUI from there , see [How do I get the GUI to come back?](http://askubuntu.com/a/57213/257256)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Boot the Ubuntu Live-Dvd/Usb.

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

Run:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose fdisk reports / is /dev/sda1, continue running:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
```

Add OpenDNS name servers to /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Paste the following into the file

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Control+O, save file. Control+X, close nano, continue running:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Boot from Hard Disk.